# qwt plot maximum height

Tags: qt, plot, qwt

I use qwt plot and need increase maximum height of plot. When the height is more than 32000px it draws black area below 32K px. What is real maximum height of the plot? P.S. I put my plot into scroll area.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QScrollArea *scroll = new QScrollArea;
    setCentralWidget( scroll );

    QwtPlot *d_plot = new QwtPlot( this );
    d_plot->setMinimumHeight(50000);

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(d_plot);
    scroll->setWidget(d_plot);
    scroll->setWidgetResizable(true);

    QwtPlotCurve *curv1 = new QwtPlotCurve(QString("C"));
    curv1->setPen(QPen(Qt::red));

    const int N1 = 262144;
    double *X1 = (double *)malloc((2*N1)*sizeof(double));
    double *Y1 = X1 + N1;

    double h = 8./(N1-1);
    for (int k = 0; k < N1; k++)
    {
        X1[k] = k*h;
        Y1[k] = cos(M_PI*X1[k]-5*M_PI/12);
    }

    curv1->setSamples(Y1,X1,N1);

    curv1->attach(d_plot);

    d_plot->replot();
}
```

black area after 32K px

[image]

Comment: Can you post some example code and add more context to your question? I want to help, and I am a qt programmer, but I would like more info. :)

Comment: Hi, Ashley. Did you use qwt plot? Just put it into scroll area and setFixedHeight(33000). Scroll down and you will see that a part of plot is black colored. It seems that qwt plot has limits of canvas drawing

Answer (score 0):

The limit should be SHRT_MAX and is a Qt limitation ( unrelated to Qwt ).